# Find the Unambiguous Grammar

Tags: formal-grammars, compilers, ambiguity

Consider the following grammar:
S->A.
A->A+A|B++.
B->y

Check whether grammar is Ambiguous or not?
Also ,unambiguate the grammar.Now please tell me what will be the grammar after removing the ambiguity.

I have worked over here and i am able to draw two parse trees for the input string w=y+++y+++y++ [image: Here i have tried to draw two parse trees]

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question? We are not here to do your homework, but rather to help you do it yourself.

Comment: Sir i have provided my own thoughts , and The grammar is ambiguous . Please tell me how to Disambiguate the grammar as whatever i am trying it is leading to Ambiguous grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, disambiguating a grammar is more of an art than a science, especially since it's known that there is no possible algorithm that will correctly decide whether a given grammar is ambiguous. For simple grammars like yours, though, there are some techniques that will work.

First, let's simplify your grammar purely for ease of explanation, replacing it with
$$
S\rightarrow A\quad A\rightarrow A+A\mid z
$$
where the terminal $z$ will represent your "$y++$". This is ambiguous, since the string $z+z+z$ gives rise to two different parse trees [*Hint 1*: do a leftmost derivation and a rightmost derivation of that expression and look at the resulting parse trees.]

The problem here is that in a derivation with $\Rightarrow A+A+\dotsm+A\Rightarrow$, we'll have too many choices for which of the $A$ variables to replace, generally giving us different parse trees depending on what choice we make. We need to change the grammar so as to eliminate those possible choices.

The key here is that your grammar will generate all and only strings of the form $z+z+\dotsm +z$, with 1 or more $z$'s. Can you find another grammar that will generate these strings, so that the right side of any production contains only at most a single variable and perhaps some terminals? [*Hint 2*: you can do this with a grammar having only one variable.]

Comment: (will this be equivalent to the above grammar after removing ambiguity) S-> A | B       A->B+C    B->y++     C-> B+ C| y++

Comment: @ChÃrmingßoy. Looks good to me.

Comment: @ChÃrmingßoy. Both of your parse trees are correct.

Comment: With increment operator, will we not check for associativity and precedance ? I think increment operator is left associative ?and so i think first increment operation should take place and then addition of first two terms and then addition of the combined result with the third increment operator so i think first will be accpeted by the parser. Because parser at a time can choose only 1 correct parse tree to evaluate the expression.

Comment: @ChÃrmingßoy. Those questions don't apply in your grammar. Sure, in a real programming language we'd have to be concerned with these details, but they are not considered in the grammar as given.

Answer (score 0):

The grammar can be tested for ambiguity by drawing parse trees for a string in the language.
If multiple parse trees exist for a given string the grammar is ambiguous.

For removing the ambiguity in the grammar you can introduce precedence in the production rules.

This looks like a homework though. Hope the answer helps you in solving the same.

Comment: I know that the grammar is ambiguous as i am getting two parse trees for the input string w=y+++y+++y++ . but i am unable to remove ambiguity.Please i beg you sir help